# Write "Monoton" Font in Latex

Tags: fonts

I want to typing "Special Function" in Monoton Font.  How to do that?
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \textbf{{\Large SPECIAL FUNCTION}}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you have that font installed in your computer, you can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Ok, thanks.for your comment.